# Using @Cacheable and @CacheEvict in Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching

I developed a method that use `@Cacheable` annotation. The code is:

```
   @Cacheable(value="reporties" , key="{#root.methodName,#manager.name}")
   public List<Employee> getReportiesForManager(Employee manager){
     // code to fetch reporties its a Spring JDBC call
   }
```

Now, I want to evict this cache after some events:

- Some reporties related with manager have been updated (added or removed).

After that, the cache related with the manager should be evicted, in that way, the application will get new data instead of using the existing one in that cache. I developed the following method for that:

```
@CacheEvict(value="reporties",key="{#name}")
public void evictReportiesCache(String name){}
```

I call inside the method which updates the relations of the Manager and its reporties. However, this one works intermittently and I am not sure if that's the correct way to evict cache. Also the Cacheable uses `#root.methodName` as part of key.

Can someone please help me with this cache eviction?

Answer (score 5):

You can think of the cache as a `Map<key, value>`.

Every time you invoke a method with the `@Cacheable` annotation you write in that `Map` a value associated to what you define as they key.

Every time you invoke a method with the `@CacheEvict` annotation you delete the value associated with the key. You can also delete all the entries in the Map.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, the value of the key you evict has to be the same than the key you cached.

Answer (score 3):

The keys passed to `Cacheable` and `CacheEvict` annotations must be the same if they are identifying the same data.

If you want to evict your *reports* cache by the manager's name, you need to both *cache* and *evict* solely based on the manager's name.

Comment: I cannot change the key of cacheable as it is not in my control.The key will have both #root.methodName and #manager.name. How to specify the methoname in cache evict to match the key of cacheable

Comment: Ok.Will try hardcoding.Thanks, But also this annotation is on lot of methods, do I need to write evict for each those cacheable methods?

Comment: You could use `@CacheEvict( value = "reporties", allEntries = true )` on one method to evict all items from the `reporties` cache.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to specify the key in order to identify the specific manager.

Comment: That manager key I will pass but what about the method name. i hardcoded the methodname but it doesn't work

Comment: Let us know how you have written the eviction annotation.