# Am I using @Cacheable, @CachePut and @CacheEvict correctly?

Tags: java, spring, caching

In my Java Spring MVC application I have a DAO that returns users.  The DAO gets hit a lot so I'm trying to cache the users.

I did it like this (below) but I don't know if I'm doing it right.

I'm thinking `@Cacheable` is making it so `getAllUsers` and `getUser` will only be run once, and all other times the value will be loaded from the cache.

And `@CacheEvict` on `saveUser` and `deleteUser` causes the cache to get cleared when an update or delete occurs.

Is that correct?  If so, when would it be appropriate to use `@CachePut`  ?

```
@Component
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Cacheable("users")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() throws Exception {
      /* ... loads then returns all user from the database ...*/
    }

    @Cacheable("users")
    public Datasource getUser(Integer userId) throws NoResultException, Exception {
      /* ... loads and returns the specified user from the database ...*/
    }

    @CacheEvict(value="users")
    public Integer saveUser(UserDTO userDTO) throws Exception {
      /* ... disassembles the userDTO and writes it to the database, return the user id ... */
    }

    @CacheEvict(value="users")
    public void deleteUser(Integer userId) throws Exception {
      /* ... deletes the user by userId ... */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856975/using-cacheable-and-cacheevict-in-spring), cache is like a `Map<key, value>`.

To use `@CacheEvict(...)` on a delete statement is correct.

```
@CacheEvict(value = 'user', key = "#id")
public void deleteUser(...)
```

So here the objective is to delete the user. Not only from the persistance layer but also from our cache. 
Please note to be careful with the parameters [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-evict).

However, when you are saving your user, you should use `@CachePut(...)` instead.

```
@CachePut(value = 'user', key = "#id")
public User saveUser(Integer id, UserDTO userDTO)
```

That is, the method is always executed and its result is placed into the cache (according to the `@CachePut(...)` options). More information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-put).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm confused about the value attribute.  For @Cacheable("users") the string "users" is the name of the cache.  Should I be using `value="users"` in @CacheEvict and @CachePut as well?  Or should it be "user" (singular) for some other reason?

Comment: I always prefer to specifically put in the attributes as it helps out when rereading the code or for others working with you. You can check about the value attribute [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html#value--). That being said, in your case I would suggest putting in ```value="users"```. The value users, if compared to the Map<key, value> analogy I made would be ```Map<key, value> users;```